# SQL Percentage and Calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a query and have some calculations in them. Now i need to do some calculations on the calculated columns.

Example

```
dbo.SI.frozqty-dbo.SI.countqty AS VARCOUNT
```

now i need to work out the percentage of

```
VARCOUNT / dbo.SI.frozqty
```

But i will not recognize VARCOUNT

Also need to remove that divide by 0 error and get that calculation in a new column using AS

Any ideas guys?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can't grab the value of a sibling column via its alias. If this is part of a Stored Procedure that is a bit more involved than what you've shown, you can use declared parameters to store your values. Otherwise, just do `SELECT dbo.SI.frozqty-dbo.SI.countqty as VARCOUNT, (dbo.SI.frozqty-dbo.SI.countqty) / dbo.SI.frozqty AS CalculatedValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subqueries or CTE. Do 1st level of calculation in subquery or CTE and use that for doing 2nd level of calculation in main query.

Answer (score 0):

The normal answer to this question is to use a subquery or CTE.  These are valid.  Another method is to use a lateral join, which in SQL Server is spelled `OUTER APPLY` or `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select x.varcount / si.frozqty
from . . . outer apply
     (select dbo.SI.frozqty-dbo.SI.countqty AS VARCOUNT) x
```

Note that SQL Server does integer division, if both arguments are integers.  This doesn't affect the `OUTER APPLY` syntax, just the result of the division.